# Vuejs - Post file not working - Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, file-upload, vue.js, laravel-spark

Here is my html:

```
<label class="btn btn-outline-info" v-if="plan">
            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Upload Appraisal<input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFilesUpload()" hidden>
        </label>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
handleFilesUpload(){
                this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0]

                let formData = new FormData()

                formData.append('appraisal', this.file)

                this.uploadAppraisal(formData)
            },
            uploadAppraisal(data) {
                axios.post( '/api/test',
                  data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }
                ).then(response => {
                  this.info = response.data
                })
                .catch(function(){
                  console.log('FAILURE!!')
                });
            }
```

On the backend I am running Laravel Spark. I am expecting to receive a file called appraisal. However, when I do this I get false:

```
    if ($request->hasFile('appraisal')) {
    //
}
```

So I am a little confused. I am submitting xml files and at this time am simply trying to json encode them and return that result. I think I am doing this right, but could be off. Any help is appreciated. Quick note: $request->appraisal does exist, it is just empty as far as I can tell.

Here is the result of print_r($request->all()) in my api:

Array ( [appraisal] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => test.xml [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/octet-stream [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 1 [hashName:protected] => [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, some deeper research revealed that I still had to change my max upload size and post size in my php.ini file. I did that and now it is working just fine.